# Can a Windows Server detect the OS of a connected RDP client?

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server

So I have a set of servers that connect that clients connect to via an RDP Remote app. We also use a custom RDP pluggin that utilizes virtual channels. The problem is these pluggins are only designed to work on Windows systems. If we have a client connecting using a mobile or apple device, certain remote app functions will not work.

If there is a way via powershell or some other windows api to get this information? If we can determine the connecting OS, we can make changes to our app to behave accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to detect the OS of the client as this would be a security issue (leaking client information).

If the virtual channel is [scriptable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380824(v=vs.85).aspx), it might be possible for the client and server to communicate via a script so you might be able to use that to indicate the presence of the client capability to the server.

If the client and server are both part of the same domain, it might be possible for the server to determine the client information via Active Directory, SCCM or similar information.

But without knowing what virtual channels you have deployed and what their capabilities are, it would not be possible to provide further information.

Comment: Shortly after asking this, what you said actually crossed my mind I decided to take things in a different direction. Thanks!